# Batch - Copy/Archivate files from directory using Date Created.

Tags: batch-file

### Good day!

So, what I am trying to do here is:

1. Archivate **ALL** .file type files, that were created in chosen Month and move them to Another directory.
2. Create backup folder with **ALL** .file type files that corespond, to chosen Month.

Here is, what I have at this moment:

```
ECHO OFF
COLOR 9E
CLS
:MENU
ECHO(
ECHO( ...............................................
ECHO(           Choose month of the year.
ECHO( ...............................................
ECHO(
ECHO 1  - January
ECHO 2  - February
ECHO 3  - March
Echo 4  - April
Echo 5  - May
Echo 6  - June
Echo 7  - July
Echo 8  - August
Echo 9  - September
Echo 10 - October
Echo 11 - November
Echo 12 - December
ECHO 13 - EXIT
ECHO(

SET /P M= Type prefered month, then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1  GOTO JANUARY
IF %M%==2  GOTO FEBRUARY
IF %M%==3  GOTO MARCH
IF %M%==4  GOTO APRIL
IF %M%==5  GOTO MAY
IF %M%==6  GOTO JUNE
IF %M%==7  GOTO JULY
IF %M%==8  GOTO AUGUST
IF %M%==9  GOTO SEPTEMBER
IF %M%==10 GOTO OCTOBER
IF %M%==11 GOTO NOVEMBER
IF %M%==12 GOTO DECEMBER
IF %M%==13 GOTO EOF

:January
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:February
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:MARCH
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]
cls
GOTO MENU

:APRIL
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:MAY
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:JUNE
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:JULY
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:AUGUST
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:SEPTEMBER
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:OCTOBER
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:NOVEMBER
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU

:DECEMBER
cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Folder

[I am stuck here]

cls
GOTO MENU
```

My problem is, company where I am working in, doesn't use Unlicensed Software. To save some money, they installed 7zip on work computers.

So, my question is:

1. How to Add **ALL** .file type files that were created in [Month], to 7zip archive, name it [MM_YYYY], and Move it to another folder.
2. How to create backup folder named [MM_YYYY] and put there only those .file type files, that corresponds to chosen month.

Comment: This code sample is far from minimal… [mcve]

Comment: It is impossible for me To Write Minimal, complete or Verifiable example, becouse I have no clue, how to make it Verifiable. I did not add it for anyone to find errors, because there is none. I asked 2 questions that you can read in bottom of post. Please, read carefully.

Comment: In what format _Date Modified_ is show for files on your PC in Windows Explorer? Also, to what _path\folder_name_ do you want to save ZIP files, and [MM_YYYY] backup folders?

Comment: Sorry for long time, no answer, and thank you for actually trying to help. Date Modified format is [DD:MM:YYYY]. 

ZIP files, that are containing files, I want to be saved on Network folder actually. It's not really important, becouse If i will be able to understand, how to save files to ZIP, I will be able to change Path easly.

As for Backup folders, here is how I wanted it to work.

Run script > Choose January > CD "Folder" > Create Folder "01_2016" > Move Files where Date Modified or Date Created == [1 - 31].01.2016 > End. 

It's probably hard to understand, sorry for bad English

Comment: @Vairis Do you have read the documentation (help file) of 7-Zip? It supports compressing files based on a file names list. So all you need to do is find all files last modified or created within selected month and redirect them into a list file in `%TEMP%`, call 7-Zip with this list file as parameter together with other parameters like archive file name and the switches and finally delete the temporary created list file. By the way: The last creation date can be __today__ for a file last modified __3 months ago__. Do you really want do work with creation instead of last modification date?

Comment: @Vairis Hint: A single license of shareware archiver *WinRAR* which must be paid only once for unlimited updates costs just 30 US$. I mention this as *WinRAR* has switches for such time based archiving tasks making it very simple to accomplish them. *WinRAR* itself can find the files within a specified time period to archive depending on various `-t` switches. Your company should think if buying a *WinRAR* license is really more expensive than the time you need to write the code for this and perhaps other archiving tasks in future for freeware archiver 7-Zip.

Comment: Hey Mofi, thank you for your help. No, I haven't read 7-zip documentation. Unfortunately, batch scripting is basicly Rocket Science for me, becouse this is literally third day, I am trying to write script :P. Could you please link me, somewhere, where I could learn about "Redirecting files into list File", I have never done that. About Creation Date/Modified Date, how is that possible to create File today, that was modified 3 months ago? :0. I mean, all of these files are created by Program automatically, that's why I chose Creation date?

Comment: Btw, yes, I've seen bunch of tutorials on how to archive multiple files using WinRar, but never found anything about 7-Zip. I would love to speak about buying WinRar in company where I work, but I am just a Student. I have to work there only for 3 months, so I can't really change anything becouse my voice is not important in such a big company. But I will definetlely chat with "co-workers" about it :)

Comment: @Vairis Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) and see also [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx) and [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/). When a file last modified 3 months ago is copied from one folder to another folder, the last modification date of file is identical for source and copy, but the copy has as creation date the current date. Try it out on a copied file with `dir file` versus `dir file /TC`.

Comment: @Mofi Thank you  very much. Got it, haha. In my case, I was really shocked when I saw that file was created 6 months after it was modified :) Also thank you very much for documentations, I will need to read them in spare time :)

Comment: @Mofi This task is not simple or obvious to approach for a novice. It does require some time to code and debug for an experience batcher as well.

Comment: @sambul35 Sorry, I forgot the word `often` in my comment `... for such time based archiving tasks making it very simple to accomplish them` between `very` and `simple`. This specific task indeed needs some additional batch code although the main problem would be easier to solve than when using currently latest version of 7-Zip with using last modified time and not the time the file was created in current folder and using `-ta` and `-tb` switches of *WinRAR* to specify a time range.

Comment: As much as I like to support batch programming - this is a plain 'script service' post and as such inappropiate. OP already stated that he's got no script to review and no knowledge about batch.

Comment: @user1016274 - I will not argue with you about script servicing, becouse that's really looks like it. BUT, that does not mean, that only thing I wanted is working code from someone... I created picked sambul35 answer as "answer" becouse he was the most helpfull. However, since I am newbie, by some more question asking, I made completely functional code myself. I am not here asking for someones codes. I am here to ask for help. You may like supporting batch scripting, but you are clearly "bad" at supporting newbies who are trying to learn batch scripting.

Comment: @user1016274 2. more things to say. 1. You should really reconsider your "like to support batch programming" becouse clearly, Mofi, and sambul35 helped me much more than you would ever do with your attitude. 2. This post was already answered, and so you have absolutely no reason to write anything in the comments. I don't know what exactly you are doing here, but it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script works well for me with your task. Change `dir` value to your real folder path. Save this script to *test.bat* in a different folder, and run from open Cmd Prompt. The script assumes date format `[DD:MM:YYYY]`. To use it with format `[MM:DD:YYYY]`, replace 0 to 3 in all occurrences of `!cmon:~0,2!`. Let me know if any errors:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "mes1=Enter the month letter"
set dir=%userprofile%\Desktop\Folder

COLOR 9E
CLS
:MENU
ECHO(
ECHO( ...............................................
ECHO(           Choose month of the year.
ECHO( ...............................................
ECHO(
ECHO J - January
ECHO F - February
ECHO M - March
Echo P - April
Echo Y - May
Echo N - June
Echo L - July
Echo U - August
Echo S - September
Echo O - October
Echo V - November
Echo D - December
ECHO X - EXIT
ECHO(

choice /c JFMPYNLUSOVDX /n /m "%mes1%: > " /t 10 /d X
IF %errorlevel% equ 13 (GOTO :end
) else if %errorlevel% LEQ 9 (set i=0%errorlevel%) else (set "i=%errorlevel%")
pushd "%dir%"
for /f "tokens=1,5" %%G in ('dir /o:d /a:-d "%dir%"') do (set cmon=%%G
    if "!cmon:~2,1!"=="/" if "!cmon:~0,2!"=="!i!" (set cdir=!cmon:~0,2!-!cmon:~6,4!
        (if not exist "!cdir!" md "!cdir!") & copy "%%H" !cdir! >nul))
pushd "!cdir!" & "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a !cdir!.zip >nul & popd

:end
echo/ & echo All tasks completed
timeout 5 >nul
exit /b
```

To better understand how the script works, see [Extracting Substrings](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

Comment: Hey, once again, thanky you very much. God bless programmers who actually like to help people. Btw, I have 1 more request from you, if you don't mind ofcourse. Could you please explain, how does this whole script works? It's really hard to analyze it, and that's why, most likely, it doesn't work as it is suposed to. When script is runned, you can choose any of displayed months, but for some reason, when ZIP is made, it pushes all files and folders into it, which would be ok, but I only needed .file type files :P. As for creating Backup in same directory, unfortunetely it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Basicly what is not working: ZIP - Is created, but with blank name, and contains all folders and .file type files, also is not sent to anywhere, because location was not set in code (That's my fault for not understanding code). Backup - Is not being created. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Did you change the dir value to your real path, where your files to backup are stored? The script assumes, you store all batches in a different directory from the files to backup. It works perfect for me. Try learning what it does step by step to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate that :) Let's hope that I will meet you again some time later :)

Comment: Zip file is saved in the newly created dir with all backup files. Folders aren't saved in .zip, only files. You can save the .zip file in any other place, but chose 7zip options carefully via its Help, since the file may contain full paths in this case.